# converting MySQL One-to-Many result set to JSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, json

I have two tables (lecture and topic) related by topic_id. I need to join the lectures as children of their related topic. The desired json_encode($result) should be:

```
[
    {"id":"2","name":"topic 3",
      "lectures": [
        {"id":"9", "topic_id":"2","name":"lecture 1"},
        {"id":"10","topic_id":"2","name":"lecture 2"},
        {"id":"11","topic_id":"2","name":"lecture 3"}
      ]
    },
    {"id":"3","name":"topic 4",
      "lectures": [
        {"id":"12","topic_id":"3","name":"lecture 1"},
        {"id":"13","topic_id":"3","name":"lecture 2"},
        {"id":"14","topic_id":"3","name":"lecture 3"}
      ]
    }
]
```

One possible solution is to regenerate the array like this

```
$topics = $db->query("select * FROM topic")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$lectures = $db->query("SELECT * FROM lecture")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($topics AS $topic) {
    $result[$topic["id"]] = $topic;
    $result[$topic["id"]]["lectures"] = array();
}
foreach($lectures AS $lecture) {
    $result[$lecture["topic_id"]]["lectures"][] = $lecture;
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

The result is:

```
[
    {"2": {"id":"2","name":"topic 3",
       "lectures": [    
        {"id":"9", "topic_id":"2","name":"lecture 1"},
    {"id":"10","topic_id":"2","name":"lecture 2"},
    {"id":"11","topic_id":"2","name":"lecture 3"}
   ]
    },
    {"3": {"id":"3","name":"topic 4",
       "lectures": [
    // ...
]
```

which is still not exactly what we require. I need to remove the top-most id (used as key) could be done either at the server or the client by regenerating the result-array, keeping only the values. The (not so elegant) solution could be:

```
$result2 = array();
foreach($result AS $res) {
    $result2[] = $res;
}
echo json_encode($result2);
```

which gets me the desired result, but the solution is far from efficient.

Any suggestion on a better way of doing this would be appreciated. Suggestion may include a more efficient way of:

- getting some work done by improving the MySQL query.
- array manipulation in php
- getting the desired result by manipulating on client-side (Javascript, jQuery or Underscore convenience method)

Thanks

Comment: can you show me the table structure of these two tables (topic, lecture)?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is slightly ambiguous so I am guessing here.  I think you need just one MySQL statement.

```
SELECT lecture.id lid,lecture.name lname,topic.id tid,topid.name tname 
FROM lecture 
LEFT JOIN topic ON lecture.id = topic.id
ORDER BY lid,tid
```

You result should then be in the correct order.